# Return group and group length using Jinja2 templating

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I have an Ansible inventory file, with a group that contains roughly 20 children groups. I want to return the list of children so I started with:

```
{% for group in groups[maingroup] %}
    {{ group }}
{% endfor %}
```

Next, how can I add next to the group its length, comma separated?

I was thinking something like this would work but it doesn't:

```
{{ group|join(',', attribute='length') }}
```

Ideal output would be:

```
group_A,3
group_B,12
group_C,26
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use `join`. You are using templating language, so use it in a simple way:

```
{% for group in groups[maingroup] %}
    {{ group }},{{ group|length }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot.